# How to run python function once user inputs into form field

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I am an html page with a form to enter your email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The form novalidate attribute</h1>

<p>The novalidate attribute specifies that the form data should not be validated when submitted.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php" novalidate>
  <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The novalidate attribute of the form tag is not supported in Safari 10 (or earlier).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to run a python script when the user enters his email address and then takes the input and runs it through this def function:

```
def send_email():
email_address=form_input
print(email_address)
```

So basically, when a user enters an email in the form, it takes the value and runs it through the send email function. I am new to using python with html so the syntax is confusing me. Any ideas or suggestions as to how to but it in the html file?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do it just in html.
If you use .php as backend script, read this [php form handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
If you want to use python as backend script, you need to use ajax, e.g. [ajax intro](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp). In this case, need to run web server that take ajax request and respond the request